# Added Row disappears jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have written a code for database updates. The problem is after a new row is added, it displays and then disappears..This page is on the server end.I tried to open the page in firefox as well as chrome, it displays and then disappears. What is the problem??

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        //$(function() { alert('hi') })
        $(document).ready(
            function () {
                $("#AddRow").click(
                    function () {
                        if ($('.checkbox').is(':checked')) {
                            {
                                //alert('hi') 
                                var row = document.getElementById("row"); // find row to copy
                                var table = document.getElementById("tabletomodify"); // find table to append to
                                var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
                                clone.id = "row0"; // change id or other attributes/contents
                                table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table

                            }

                        }
                    }

                );
            }
        );
    </script>
</head>



<table cellpadding="10" style="border:2px solid black;" id="tabletomodify">

    <tr bgcolor="#360584">
        <td style="border:1px solid black;" colspan="15"><font face="Arial" size="4" color="white"><b><i>Records</i></b></font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button id="AddRow">Add Row</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="DuplicateRow">Duplicate Row</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="DeleteRow">Delete Row</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#360584">
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">Name </font>
        </td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">Date of Birth</font>
        </td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">City</font>
        </td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">State</font>
        </td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">Country</font>
        </td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">Phone Number</font>
        </td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">Mail ID</font>
        </td>


        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">Select</font>
        </td>



        <tr id="row">
            <td>
                <select></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
            </td>

        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It seems to work correctly in this fiddle I made... I select the box on the right and add row and it stays in chrome.  http://jsfiddle.net/AdamDrummond/DzkB5/

Comment: Interesting, I tested it and did not see any issue. ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PvUDv.png) Am I testing correctly?

Comment: If it appears, then disappears, it would seem that the page is reloading.

Comment: pasted the code in the jsfiddle created by adam .. working fine now..

Comment: My code is  hard coded.To make this code even more flexible, right now it adds one row to the table.. so i will be having 2 rows.. what change should i make in the code so that if i select 2 rows, it should append 2 more rows.. select 10 rows and append 10 more rows?? and also.. how do i make the newly rows'/row's checkbox to be deselected by default?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I recently had a similar problem. Turned out that using the HTML tag `<button>` was the issue. If you put the button in a form it will cause the page to reload, which results in the issue you reported. Although you don't have your button in a form, perhaps you didn't post to us exactly what's on your page? I suspect this is the case as you don't have a body tag in your HTML.

Simplest fix is to use `< input type="button"/>` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a fiddle with the same html and cleaned up JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/krmFU/

```
$("#AddRow").click(function () {
    if ($('.checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        {
            alert('hi');
            var row = document.getElementById("row"); // find row to copy
            var table = document.getElementById("tabletomodify"); // find table to append to
            var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
            clone.id = "row0"; // change id or other attributes/contents
            table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
        }
    }
});

<table cellpadding="10" style="border:2px solid black;" id="tabletomodify">
    <tr bgcolor="#360584">
        <td style="border:1px solid black;" colspan="15"><font face="Arial" size="4" color="white"><b><i>Records</i></b></font>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button id="AddRow">Add Row</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="DuplicateRow">Duplicate Row</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="DeleteRow">Delete Row</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#360584">
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">Name </font>

        </td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">Date of Birth</font>

        </td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">City</font>

        </td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">State</font>

        </td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">Country</font>

        </td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">Phone Number</font>

        </td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">Mail ID</font>

        </td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">Select</font>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row">
        <td>
            <select></select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select></select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select></select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select></select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select></select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select></select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select></select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, but -1. Neither of those are necessary.